# How to port Laravel 5.0 Encryption to Objective C

Tags: android, objective-c, laravel, encryption, porting

We are currently trying to port the Laravel [encryption/decryption](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php) to Objective C and Android.

We have achieved the port to Android, the code looks like this;

```
public static String encrypt(byte[] keyValue, String plaintext) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
    //serialize
    String serializedPlaintext = "s:" + plaintext.length() + ":\"" + plaintext + "\";";
    byte[] plaintextBytes = serializedPlaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] iv = c.getIV();
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(plaintextBytes);
    String encryptedData = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "HmacSHA256");
    Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    hmacSha256.init(macKey);
    hmacSha256.update(Base64.encode(iv, Base64.NO_WRAP));
    byte[] calcMac = hmacSha256.doFinal(encryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String mac = new String(Hex.encodeHex(calcMac));
    //Log.d("MAC",mac);

    AesEncryptedData aesData = new AesEncryptedData(
            Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.NO_WRAP),
            encryptedData,
            mac);

    String aesDataJson = new Gson().toJson(aesData);

    return Base64.encodeToString(aesDataJson.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

But the Objective C part is troubling us the most, we are not able to replicate Laravel's encryption mechanism. The `mac` generation part seems to be hardest one. If anyone has some idea, on how the port could look like in objective c that would be really helpful.

Comment: This is all doable, they are just primitive functions. You need to do several things: 1 Provide your code as a base, I doubt that anyone will write your code for you here. We are happy to help with code. 2. Provide hex dumps of the test parameters, key, iv, data in, data out and intermediate in hex for both the existing Laravel and ObjC attempts. 3. Links to the Cipher, SecretKeySpec, AesEncryptedData methods.

Comment: My goal is not someone to write code for me, I am myself trying to help a fellow developer, on this problem she is having. She isn't that good in writing in the English language. Therefore I wrote the question for her.

Comment: @zaph 
Hi, i am now trying to do the client iOS encrypt/decrypt with [FBEncryptorAES](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor).

Here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/zyQ1w0Nq) that i am testing.
in the FBEncryptor configuration i have: 

#define FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM     kCCAlgorithmAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE    kCCBlockSizeAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE         kCCKeySizeAES128

It seems that the "mac" value is not valid in the php decryption.

Please let me know if i should provide any other details about this issue.

Comment: Make sure the key sie matched the actual key size. When you have more information it is generally better to add it to the question so everyone will see it easily and there is formatting. Code needs to be added and hex dumps supplied. FBEncryptorAES is not a particiularly good choice, it hasn't been updated in 4 years. The good news is that it used Common Crypto, the bad news it is still does not use the Apple Base64 implementation.

Comment: @TimurX. hello i am so happy for find this conversation. you set some sample code for this in a link, but that code has been removed. :( ... I need that code .please help me . if is it possible set that code in another link. Thank you so so much

Comment: @zaph Hello if you have some code for this goal please  set it at link .i need it . please help me. thank you

Comment: @KreshnikHasanaj Hello do u have code for objective c or swift ?

Comment: @reza_khalafi i will upload the code on github.

Comment: Thank you so much @TimurX. , I am waiting for link.